# Android HttpsURLConnection throw generic Exception without details

Tags: java, android

Hy guys,

I'm struggling with a difficult problem.
I need to call a web service with REST GET method over HTTPS.
The code is as follows:

```
URL urlSSL = new URL ("https: // xxxxxxxx");
HttpsURLConnection URLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) urlSSL.openConnection ();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod ("GET");
```

Immediately after this statement the value of getResponseCode is -1.
If I try to read the stream of input

```
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream ();
```

an exception is raised and it is generic Exceptio details.
I have no more ideas for the solution.
Could you please help me?

Thank You.

Comment: Just post a Stacktract, it might be due to certification not trusted exception  read more about it here https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

Comment: Step forward, now I obtain java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: You need to add one certificate digest in trust manager, check the link i posted above.

Comment: thank you, the article is so difficult to understand. I cannot find an example to implement the trust manager for ignore the certificate if not recognized.